# Best way to overload a function based on argument type being pointer | reference?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I have a function like so:

```
void myFunction(MyObject& obj)
{
    //lots of code to operate on obj
}
```

My issue is that sometimes obj will be a pointer to an instance of the type MyObject

```
void myFunction(MyObject* obj)
{
    //...
}
```

My question is how can I achieve having both function definitions, while not having to repeat any code?

Comment: I am not sure. Personally I would settle for one or other. Then, if needed, pass in &rObject or *pObject. That has worked for me.

Comment: You can always call one function from the other, but I don't think you really need two, the caller can provide either easily.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply forward the instance on from the pointer function.

```
void myFunction(MyObject* obj)
{
    if (obj != nullptr) // do not want to dereference a null pointer
        myFunction(*obj);
}
```

Will call the reference version of `myFunction` allowing you to only maintain one function.

This assumes that you only need to work with the value of the object and using a pointer or reference is to just save having to copy the object.

Comment: Cool. I was not sure that would compile. But my comment implies something similar. But you did better. 

Comment: I would check for `nullptr` first before forwarding to the reference version of `myFunction`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good suggestion.  I added a check into the code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do it the other way around? From the reference function to the pointer function, since a reference cannot be ever null, no checkings would be required...

Comment: @LoPiTaL You would still need the null check in the pointer version as the OP has values and pointers so I don't think it matters.  Plus the OP already has the code in the reference version so I did not want to change that.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that the OP original version was the refrence one.

Comment: Yes the goal is to avoid having to copy the object and also not have to repeat code.